# How to prevent Windows 7 from 'thinking' my c:\ boot drive is a network drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, shared-folders

I've a very strange problem with my Windows 7 SP1 x64 installation. The system has a 256 GB SSD with two partitions, `c:\` and `d:\`.

When I create a new folder on `c:\`, say `c:\test` and copy, and launch any non-signed executable there, I get the

> Publisher Could Not Be Verified

warning. This warning is common if you start a executable from a mapped network drive, but I have not seen it on any of my local drives for 5 years.

If I copy the same executable to a folder on `c:\` that was created more than 1 month ago there is no warning. If I create a new folder on `d:\`, say d:\test, and copy exactly the same executable there, there is no warning.

So a warning comes only if I put an executable in a folder that is freshly created, and present on `c:\` (`d:\` does not have the problem also with new folders).

There are other symptoms. Any app that is launched with the warning is not able to write to Registry at all, not even to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. It just generates

> failed to create key

exceptions. The same app copied to a folder on `c:\` (no matter which as long as it was created more than 1 month ago), and both the warning and the inability to write to Registry goes away.

I've googled for 4 hours, but didn't find a similar case.

What I've tried so far:

- reset of security zones in control panel internet properties
- used a takeown script to modify the rights of the folders/files
- starting the apps as administrator does not help (warning remains, and no registry write access). uac is turned off anyway.
- file system check (no errors)
- looked for funny things in `HLCU` + `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags`

To no avail.

How to prevent Windows 7 from 'thinking' my `c:\` boot drive is a network drive?

Comment: I have some more information. It's not a Registry-only problem. It's a global read only problem that includes files. Any app started from a folder that is freshly created has read-only access to ALL files on all partitions, even if started with admin rights. I've also tried to create a second admin user, but with the new account the problem remains the same. Something must have happened on 07/04/2015 on my system, so all folders created after that time have very strange system rights that are read only.

Comment: Even this test fails: 1. created c:\testfolder 2. Copied notepad.exe from c:\windows\system32 to c:\testfolder 3. right clicked notepad.exe and selected 'run as administrator' 4. typed random text and tried to save to my documents folder. Notepad gives an error message that I don't have permission to save in this location. if I do the same test with d:\testfolder (also freshly created), notepad is able to save!

Comment: Have you shared C: ? See [this article](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000534.htm) on how to list all shares.

Comment: Yes, C is shared, but removing the share does not solve the problem. I've also tried  sfc /scannow and disabling DEP, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Yes. Same problem in Safe mode.

Comment: have you tried creating, then restoring a clone of the SSD?

Comment: Please post a screenshot in the Properties of C: of the settings shown by the Advanced button in the Security tab.

Comment: Not tried to clone the ssd, as I thought all the access rights will be cloned. Properties screenshot here: http://i.imgur.com/EY0uayB.png

Comment: more information: if after copying notepad.exe to c:\testfolder this is used: "icacls notepad.exe /setintegritylevel High" from command line, notepad is able to save data!

Comment: My permissions on C are a bit different on Authenticates Users: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dLeMh.jpg

Comment: You might try to set up the permissions as in my image above.

Comment: I did (set everything to the state of a freshly installed c:\ partition in  Win 7 on vmware). Unfortunately it's not a solution.

Comment: NTFS supports what is called a zone identifier. For some reason, it sounds like when you are adding the folder, it gets flagged. The only time I saw this happen personally was when a colleague would open an attachment, then "save as" to a network share. The file showed up in explorer, but the windows explorer search tool would ignore it. If the person used the "save attachment" option, the file would not get flagged. ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/11/04/10463035.aspx ; http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/07/detecting-and-changing-files-internet.html )

Comment: Note that if you unzip a flagged file, the resultant folders/files will probably inherit this even when moved. @alexatkinson's answer is the way to get them "trusted" via the UI, but check your save-as behavior to see if you should do something differently. A new folder created via an untrusted executable's file dialogs may flag the folder and files as well.

Comment: Since there is no 'unblock' button I don't think it's a zone problem. It's an elevation problem, as  "icacls file.exe /setintegritylevel High" solves the problem for a single file (but needs to be done on all new folders all the time).

Answer (score 1):

You have probably destroyed the permissions on C. This drive is special and one should never just overwrite brutally all its permissions, since they are very
hard (even impossible) to recreate exactly as before.

Try to repair Windows as described in
[How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).
This mode of soft installation will fix your currently installed Windows 7 while preserving your user accounts, data, programs, and system drivers.

If this does not help, you will need to reinstall Windows.
Do not go this way without preparations.

Comment: Repair install did not help (but has created a bunch of other problems, so I have restored a backup).

Comment: [Run ckdsk](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/) as a last effort to find out what's wrong. If this doesn't help, and your disk is too destroyed even for Repair install to work, then the only solution is to format it and reinstall everything. Make sure that you have all the required installation media, drivers and serial numbers. Let me know if you require help in that.

Comment: I did already before creating the question and mentioned it in the question: "file system check (no errors)"

Comment: Then that leaves reformat as the only solution I can think of. Your problem is unique, so even if we were to understand how disk permissions were modified in that strange way, it is doubtful that one could restore them to the original state. If you choose to reformat, I suggest never again to make sweeping permissions changes to folders on C. If you have difficulty with that, partition your disk into two: C: for system and apps and D: for your data.

Answer (score 0):

In your start menu , search for **Run** dialog box.

Type **gpedit.msc**, then select **OK**.

Go to **User Configuration** > **Administrative Templates** > **Windows Components** > **Attachment Manager**.

Open the **Inclusion list for moderate risk file types** setting.

Set the policy to **Enabled**, then add ***.exe**; or whatever the file extension you are using to the “Specify high risk extensions” box.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Right click the .exe in question, click 'Properties'. At the bottom of the Properties dialog window on the General tab, click the 'Unblock' button. If it's not there, or greyed out, move it to the desktop, Unblock it, then move it back. Enjoy.

Comment: There is no unblock button. Also not if file is moved to desktop. Also not a single file is problematic, but all files that are in folders that are newly created.